# Overflow menu item redirects to facebook, twitter, instagram applications etc

Tags: android, android-intent

I am able to redirect the menu items to their particular website via mobile's browser. But I want users to redirect into these social networking website's
application if they have installed in their device.

These is my simple code for facebook redirecting to its website in my mobile's browser. Please help me reach to the application instead.

```
    case R.id.facebook:
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com/?_rdr=p";
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url)));
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void redirect(packageName, url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    try {
        Intent inAppIntent = intent;
        inAppIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        startActivity(inAppIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

call this method like:

for Facebook: `redirect("com.facebook.katana", url);`

for Instagram: `redirect("com.instagram.android", url);`

for Twitter: `redirect("com.twitter.android", url);`

Facebook is not working now. I think they changed something. Please go to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26820796/4557274)